# Trouble evaluating user input

Tags: java

So I've been working on this Java program where the computer asks the user if he wants to know the square of a number. If the user's answer is either 'Y' or 'y', the computer asks the user the number he wants he wants to know the square of, and prints the square of the number. Then the computer asks the user if he wants to know the square of another number. If answer is 'Y' or 'y', the computer takes a number and prints the square. The user is again asked if he wants to know the square of another number. Like this it goes on.

I've also written code for cases where the user's answer is negative, or neither positive nor negative. By this, I meant cases where the user's answer is 'N' or 'n'. This program runs into a problem somewhere, and does not work from A to Z the way I want it to. See, when I run the code, the computer asks me if I want to know the square of a number, and I enter 'y'. I then get asked the number I want to know the square of. I enter the number and the computer prints out its square. Then I get asked if I want to know the square of another number. I enter 'y'. Then I am asked the number I want to know the square of and I enter a number. The computer prints the square of the number. Then the program asks if I want to know the square of another number and just ends, whereas it was supposed to take my answer. I've been working for almost 16 to 17 hours trying to find the bug, but I couldn't. Could you please maybe test the code and tell me where I went wrong? Thanks.

This is the code:

```
package looppracticea;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopPracticeA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner geek = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner geek2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        long taken_number, taken_number2;
        String answer, answer2, answer_not_recognized, if_answer_is_no;
        answer_not_recognized = "You didn't enter any of the recognized answers.";
        if_answer_is_no = "'Kay. Whatever.";

        System.out.println("Do you want to know the square of a number? (Y/N)");
        answer = geek.nextLine();

        if (answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("The number you want to know the square of is:");
            taken_number = geek.nextLong();
            System.out.println("That number squared is " + taken_number * taken_number + ".");
            System.out.println("Do you want to know the square of another number? (Y/N)");
            answer2 = geek2.nextLine();

            switch (answer2) {
                case "N":
                    System.out.println(if_answer_is_no);
                    break;
                case "n":
                    System.out.println(if_answer_is_no);
                    break;

                case "Y":
                    while (answer2.equals("Y")) {
                           System.out.println("The number you want to know the square of is:");
                           taken_number2 = geek2.nextLong();
                           System.out.println("That number squared is " + taken_number2 * taken_number2 + ".");
                           System.out.println("Do you want to know the square of another number? (Y/N)");
                           answer2 = geek2.nextLine();
                    }
                break;

                case "y":
                    while (answer2.equals("y")) {
                           System.out.println("The number you want to know the square of is:");
                           taken_number2 = geek2.nextLong();
                           System.out.println("That number squared is " + taken_number2 * taken_number2 + ".");
                           System.out.println("Do you want to know the square of another number? (Y/N)");
                           answer2 = geek2.nextLine();
                    }
                break;

                default:
                    System.out.println(answer_not_recognized);
                    break;
            }


        } else if (answer.equals("N") || answer.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println(if_answer_is_no);
        } else {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(answer_not_recognized);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't you post this exact same question a few minutes ago?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question repeatedly?

Comment: Because the previous edition was ill-constructed. Could you please kindly just answer the question?

Comment: Two scanners on the same stream is a **really** bad idea.

Comment: Answered the question below, the problem was that you need to read the `nextLine` 2 times. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the fixed contents of your main:

```
        Scanner geek = new Scanner(System.in);

        long taken_number;
        String answer;
        String answer_not_recognized = "You didn't enter any of the recognized answers.";
        String if_answer_is_no = "'Kay. Whatever.";
        boolean firstTime = true;

        while(true)
        {
            if(firstTime)
                System.out.println("Do you want to know the square of a number? (Y/N)");
            else
                System.out.println("Do you want to know the square of another number? (Y/N)");
            answer = geek.nextLine();
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            {
                System.out.println("The number you want to know the square of is:");
                taken_number = geek.nextLong();
                System.out.println("That number squared is " + taken_number * taken_number + ".");
                answer = geek.nextLine();
            }
            else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                System.out.println(if_answer_is_no);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(answer_not_recognized);
                break;
            }
            if(firstTime)
                firstTime = false;
        }
```

The problem is you have to read the line twice to get to the line you want.

The first `nextLine` will read the <kbd>enter</kbd>

Also I reduced the code by:

- leaving only one `Scanner` since that is enough
- used `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of 2 `equals`
- used only one `answer` and `taken_number` variable since that was enough
- put the variables declaration on separate lines because it is easier to maintain an a convention.
- combined both input readings into one, with a boolean telling me if it is the first time so I know what message to output.
- reading the `nextLine()` 2 times because the first one is the <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: This was clearly a homework dump, and you've taken the OP's code, completely rewritten it, and effectively done their homework for them. Not only does that not teach them anything practical about coding, it encourages people to post more homework dumps with the expectation that the SO community will just do their work for them.

Comment: I explained the code and where he should improve. Pointed out his problem in the original code and explained why it happened. I think this has more teaching impact than not answering at all or leaving his code intact.

Comment: JonK said that I did wrong to answer your question and I explained him why I didn't.

Comment: I'm not taking issue with the fact that you answered - that's what SO is all about after all. My issue is that your answer is essentially "here's some new code, I did your work for you" with a summary of what you changed afterwards. It may not be true in this case, but 99% of the time the asker is just going to copy/paste the code without making any effort to try and understand it. We can answer homework questions *without* doing all of the asker's work for them. Teach them to fish instead of just giving them the fish, if you will.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about and promote that myself. But you should also have in sight the fact that some people learn a lot more from seeing code with explanation why it is there, than 2-3 times as much explanations. Also he mentioned that he spent 16-17 hours on the problem and posted his 99% done homework, that is enough in my opinion. If you still think that in this scenario I deserved a downvote than I respect your decision.